# What does FormsAuthentication.Initialize() do?

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication

What, specifically, does the `FormsAuthentication.Initialize()` method actually do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When in doubt, use [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/).  Unfortunatly, I;m not sitting at my development PC so I can't tell you eaxctly, what it does, but with Reflector you should be able to find out in a matter of seconds.

Answer (score 4):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.initialize.aspx

The Initialize method is called when the  FormsAuthenticationModule creates an instance of the  FormsAuthentication class. This method is not intended to be called from your code.